# Javascript "missing ) after argument list"

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use this `Javascript`snippet below to display a `DIV`in a view Dynamically. But it gives me this error `new:624 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` for this line in the snippet `$("#order_country"]).change(function() {`

```
window.onload = function() {
 $("#order_country"]).change(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  $("#country_div").toggle(val == "us");
});
});
```

I really can't find the missing `)`, could anyone take a look at this and see if they can find it.

Comment: `$("#order_country"])` here's an error (closing bracket) - should be `$("#order_country")`

Comment: Thanks, How could I not see this, but now the console gives me another error `new:628 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )` for the `});` at the bottom

Comment: Just skip the last `)` :) Last line should look like: `};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make the line appear and disappear dynamically, you'll need to use javascript:

```
$(function() {
  $("#id-you-give-to-country_select"]).change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $("#id-you-give-to-div").toggle(val == "us");
  });
});
```

One gotcha is that in your if you're comparing `:country` (symbol) with "US" (string), which will never succeed.

#### Edit

Just for testing, you can also add `alert(val);` right after the call to `toggle`, so you can see that the code is running and what the values are.

**EDIT - THIS VERSION WORKS**

First, the `country-select` has an `ID` generated in the `html`, it is `#order_country`

Then I had to make few adjustments to the code, below is the working version

```
window.onload = function() {
  $("#order_country").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $("#country_div").toggle(val == "US");
  });
};
```

Comment: Ok thanks, but this Javascript isn´t working as expected. It doesn´t make it dynamic

Comment: Couple questions just to narrow it down: did you manage to give ids to both the country_select dropdown and the div you want to toggle? (checking via the browser's inspector is usually the easiest) Did you also remove the `if` statement, so that the div is always present on the page for the javascript to find? You could also try checking the browser's javascript console to see if there are any errors.

Comment: Hi, I added a update with the code I changed. I added `id's`to the div and the `country_select` The Javascript console isn´t showing any errors.

Comment: Okay, that looks good! Other things to check: the javascript snippet should be run after the page is loaded - I've updated the example.  You could also try putting `alert(val)` in the callback just to make sure it's running when you change the dropdown.

Comment: Hmm - can you explain in more detail what's not working? Does the `alert` not show when you change the dropdown? Does the alert message show, but the div doesn't hide/show?

Comment: The alert is not showing, and the div doesn't hide or show, I edited the Javascript as it is for now